# only one popup show in any page using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, popup, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a **worklight mobile hybrid application**. In this application we want to **show one popup** in **all pages** when **internet is not available** in that time only.

So, **I want** to write a **single popup code and I want to call that popup in any time and anywhere**. Please anyone how to do this kind of requirement.

Comment: Is your problem how to show popup or you want to find out if internet is not available and handle it at one place ?

Answer (score 0):

Open main.js, which is available to all "pages", put there your `function myPopup()` and call `myPopup` whenever you need to display it.

In each page you can call another function, which checks for internet connectivity, and if `false`, then call `myPopup`.